# Could not load file or assembly xxx or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, oracle, iis

I get the "Could not load file or assembly xxx or one of its dependencies*********" error when I host my website on a Windows Server 2012 (IIS 8). The xxx here is my project name in my local VS 2015. The application is working perfectly fine in my local PC

It is a VB.NET application with Oracle 12c database as it's backend.

Things I have tried till now.
1. Publish with setting the Target CPU as "Any CPU" and Configuration as "Release-Any CPU" - Still the same error.
2. In the Server IIS, I have set the Enable 32-but apps as True on App's App pool. This is giving a different error. - Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Please help.

Comment: Have you checked the framework version in the IIS App pool? 1. IIS > Application Pools > Select current app pool. 2. Check the user (server) has access to the directory where your assemblies are located.

Comment: Hi JFT, Thanks for your response. 
The .NET CLR Version is v4.0.30319. The server accesses the directory by IISUSRS right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your Oracle.DataAccess dll is a 64 bit dll.  You can see what driver is loaded on the web server by navigating in Windows Explorer to the \windows\assembly folder.
[image]

Most applications that are built with the Any CPU option will have the checkbox in the project settings to prefer 32 bit.  To avoid this, change your project's platform target to be a 64 bit.

[image]

Then you do not need to "Enable 32 bit" in your application pool and your problem should disappear.  Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi Dacke. Thanks a lot for your help. It works now.

I changed the platform target to x64 and while publishing i changed the configuration to "Release - x64". I can successfully host the website on IIS with enabling the 32-bit.

One last question though. I have 3 version of Oracle DataAccess in windows->assembly. 
1. Version-1.102.5.0
2. Version - 2.121.2.0
3. Version - 2.112.3.0

On the server in winodws->assembly i have only version of Oracle.DataAccess i.e. Version 2.121.2.0. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes as you can see from my screen shot I have three drivers installed on my development box.  Most application servers will only have one installed.  I have taken to making this a configurable property in my application configuration so that I can accommodate whatever version they have upon deployment.  You indicated that -enabled 32 bit- in the application pool on IIS?  If you are building a 64 bit application why did you do this?

Comment: Hi Dacke, Yes i shouldn'y have enabled for 32-bit. I was just trying out the suggestions as part of google result